# Prove this restriction with the Mean Value Theorem

Tags: calculus

I don't have any idea how to prove this by using  the Mean Value Theorem:
$$\frac{1}{n+1} \leq \ln(n+1)-\ln(n) \leq \frac{1}{n}$$

Comment: Help me please ..!

Comment: Just apply the theorem to $f(x) = \ln x$ on $[n, n+1]$.

Answer (score 1):

For every $n \geq 1$ we have
$$
\log (n+1) - \log n \leq (n+1-n)\sup_{n < t < n+1}\frac{1}{t} = \frac{1}{n}
$$
and
$$
\log (n+1) - \log n \geq (n+1-n)\inf_{n < t < n+1}\frac{1}{t} = \frac{1}{n+1}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The function $\;\dfrac1x$ is decreasing on $\mathbf R^{>0}$.

Comment: ... and $\log(n+1)-\log(n) = \int_{n}^{n+1}\frac{dx}{x}.$

Comment: Yes, but the Mean Value Theorem works as well. Two sides of the same coin.